# How to resolve auto adding rows in grid view using a windows application

Tags: c#

I was working with grid-view,I try to enter some text on cell 1 on 0th row
it automatically increment other rows and I again try to write some on cell 2 on the same 0th  row ,Simultaneously increments other rows.

So for I tried with

```
dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows=true;
```

It doesn't allow me to write inside a gridview, I think click rows has to generate automatically.

Please resolve this logic based on Cell Value Changed events.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. please read this article before asking a question  to make sure that you get a good answer http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to add rows to your gridview. If you want to add something to your view, add them to the data that you are binding to it, and then bind. Very easy.

So you have something like this:

```
List<MyType> data = ReadDataFromSomewhere();
data.Add(new MyType(){StringItem="Something", IntItem =0});//Adding your row
data.Insert(1,new MyType(){StringItem="Other Thing", IntItem =1});//Inserting to position 1    
gv.DataSource = data;
gv.DataBind();
```